# Apposition at the end of sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, appositives

I think in the following sentence I used apposition at the end of sentence, I would like to know is it a correct way to introduce an apposition?

> If  this rule be applied on the elements of the page, all such elements will be removed, regardless of their locations in the page, **even if they be inside the main content.**

Comment: The first "*be*" and the last "*be*" look out of place.  Be simpler: "*If this rule **is** applied..., even if they **are** inside ...*".  Also, perhaps not "*will* be removed" but "*shall* be removed" (the elements don't have any will to will to be removed).